# Sending SMS to dynamic Telephone number

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sms

I have an app which sends an sms and then calls a dynamic telephone number, here is the code:

```
    #pragma mark - PictureListMainTableCellDelegate methods
-(void)pictureListMainTableCell:(PictureListMainTableCell *)cell wantsToCallNumber:(NSString *)number
{

    MFMessageComposeViewController *messageComposer =
    [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
    NSString *message = @"Your Message here";
    [messageComposer setBody:message];
    messageComposer.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"0003233",        nil];
    messageComposer.messageComposeDelegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:messageComposer animated:YES completion:nil];
    NSLog(@"Texting telephone number [%@]", messageComposer);

    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@", number];
    NSLog(@"calling telephone number [%@]", number);
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    NSLog(@"%@", [self deviceLocation]);
}
```

the telephone call works but not the sms, can anyone help?

Comment: Are checking `canSendText` somewhere? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/MFMessageComposeViewController/canSendText

Comment: no i am not checking that

Comment: The link I posted leads directly to that method.

Comment: okk thanks, what will happen if the device cannot?

Answer (score 0):

First check if your device can send SMS messages by:

```
if ( [MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText] ) {
    // build your text message like you posted
}
else {
    // handle appropriately
    // no point in trying to display the compose view controller
}
```

Whether this solves your specific problem, I am not sure, since I am just following [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009668-CH1-DontLinkElementID_1) for this.

Comment: thanks, its all working now but when the user presses the button the sms doesnt automatically send; you have to press the send button, is there a way for it to send automatically?

Comment: @IdsSurrrrr As per the docs, no. The user must voluntarily send the SMS.

Answer (score 0):

just replace this line in your method and you'll be able to send dynamic messages

```
messageComposer.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:number,nil];
```

and you can send emails and messages automatically without pressing send button but in that case there is a chance of rejecting of your app from the apple app store as it is not under their legal process so they'll reject your application.

and you should check condition for

```
if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
```

otherwise in iPad and iPod your application might meet crash.